# Geth bus fatal error

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, testnets, bug

My geth node (v1.4.18 on testnet) has unexpectedly go down throwing an error like this:

```
I1028 04:46:29.305710 ethash.go:259] Generating DAG for epoch 44 (size 1442839168) (0016bedd7bd1a4976b855daf38926317ac50d2ff306182c9c1f0c61fddfff77b)
I1028 04:46:37.202844 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 195 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 95 txs in 8.0030203s. #1323724 [d3e89d0e / 248089b1]
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0x7fcce9996000 pc=0xb38b76]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0xd3ba06, 0x2a)
        /usr/lib/go-1.7/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95
runtime.sigpanic()
        /usr/lib/go-1.7/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:12 +0x2cc

goroutine 70 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0xb36760, 0xc42300bab8, 0xc400000000)
        /usr/lib/go-1.7/src/runtime/cgocall.go:131 +0x110 fp=0xc42300ba50 sp=0xc42300ba10
github.com/ethereum/ethash._Cfunc_ethash_full_new_internal(0x7fd8f8000900, 0x97a4d17bddbe1600, 0x17639238af5d856b, 0xc9826130ffd250ac, 0x7bf7ffdd1fc6f0c1, 0x55fffa80, 0x7fd8f8000940, 0xb39c40, 0x0)
        ??:0 +0x51 fp=0xc42300bab8 sp=0xc42300ba50
...
```

Any idea about it? Is it a go-Ethereum bug? How can I fix it? Thx!